# Golang execute functions at specific times

Tags: go, timer, triggers, cron

I am having some problems figuring out how to implement a cron-like feature in my program.

I have been trying https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron with some success, but can't fully figure it out.

My code current look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
)

func first() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("@every 5s", func() {fmt.Println("First", 1) })
    c.AddFunc("@every 5s", func() {fmt.Println("First", 2) })
    c.Start()
}

func second() {
    c := cron.New()
    for i := 1; i<=2; i++ {
        c.AddFunc("@every 5s", func() {fmt.Println("Second", i) })
    }
    c.Start()
}

func main() {
    first()
    second()
}
```

The first() function works like I expect it to. Every five seconds, I get two rows; one saying "First 1", and the other "First 2".

The second() function however is what is causing me problems.
I expected similar behavior, but instead every 5 seconds, I get two rows saying "Second 3".

Anyone able to explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: see: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: @JimB Thanks! That solved it for me